# Radarwidth beyond label chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm drawing a radarchart with chart.js for responsive design (for every device) and I want the radar go beyond the labels beginning.

This is my chart now:
[image]

I want to display the chart like this (that the radar is bigger on small devices):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make the labels appear inside the chart so I think the best thing to do is to set `maintainAspectRatio: false` to make the chart take more space on mobile.

It would end up like this:

[image]

Demo: https://codepen.io/adelriosantiago/pen/bGedaGZ?editors=1010

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately the view is at max size already.